# Why is Shell/Bash printf adding some rubbish at the and of message? or Server Side rubbish addition.

Tags: c, bash, shell, printf, netcat

I have a problem with this command:

```
printf 'Hello, iterative udp server!' | nc -u 192.168.8.100 2016 -w 1
```

It is adding some rubbish at the end like:

```
Hello, iterative udp server!??
```

or on server side:

```
server: received 'Hello, iterative udp server��'
```

When I use more characters it seems to work fine... I am a little confused with this.

Server is receiving this in such way:

```
 if( (n_recv = recvfrom(ps_fd, buf, sizeof(buf)-1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr, &peer_addr_len)) < 0 ) {
           fprintf(stderr, "recvfrom: %s\n", strerror(errno))
           break;
    }
  buf[n_recv] = '\0';
```

UPDATED! 
It seems that this rubbish is added when I am copying buf to datagram field in some structure that is used later to send response back to the client.

```
runner_attr->datagram = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(datagram));
memcpy(runner_attr->datagram, datagram, strlen(datagram));
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How do you send the data and how do you print? Also your posted code won't compile due to lack of semicolon after `fprintf()`.

Comment: What willl happen if you add null symbol **\0**: `Hello, iterative udp server!\0` ?

Comment: I have debbugged it and the problem seems to be on the server side rather then with shell printf

Comment: Try to use `(strlen(datagram)+1)` in `malloc` and `memcpy` functions calls! You just don't copy null termination byte.

Comment: Yeah it works now correctly  malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(datagram)+1))

Comment: I consider whether  malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(datagram))) and strcpy(runner_attr->datagram, datagram) also works correctly

Comment: Because `strcpy` copies null termination byte.

Comment: Yeah but there is theoretically allocated less space than needed and I suppose it could fail if there wasn't be place after allocated memory. Am I right?